# Create an xls from a xlt

Tags: excel, c#-4.0

Ok I have a excel template file which contains various headers, images etc.

I need to populate a number of excel files based on this template file using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`

I have seen plenty of examples online how to create and modify existing excel files (both xlt and xls) however none show how to create the xls from an xlt.

The only way I can see round the problem is to open the xlt, populate the data on the workbook then save the file as an xls....

Is this the only way that this can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using xlt and xls files you can create a standard xlsx file and use unique tokens for the content you want to replace.  Then you can create a new xlsx file based on your "template".

**Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office**

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en

Comment: Hi Samuel, thanks for the reply, I am aware of OpenXML, however I cant garuentee that the people who open the excel documents have a excel version that can read xlsx files?

Comment: @jpgooner, actually, I disagree with that.  Microsoft has always had file converters available for Excel 2003 to read Excel 2007 and later files.  Especially now that Excel 2007 and 2010 have been out for so long and so many xlsx files are shared amongst colleagues that most people will have the file converter available.  You can also link to it from your site. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=941b3470-3ae9-4aee-8f43-c6bb74cd1466&displaylang=en